# Resetting the shape of input placeholder in a tensorflow meta graph

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a neural network in tensorflow. At the time of training, I explicitly defined the shape of my input placeholder for a batch size of 20, like this `[20,224,224,3]`. I defined the batch size explicitly because thee was a `split` layer in the network and passing `None` as a batch size was throwing error on that. Is there any way that I can change the shape of input placeholder at inference time so that I can make my inference on a single image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the *.meta file of saved checkpoint you can reset the input to the graph.

```
# Set the correct data type and shape; shape can be (None, 224, 224, 3) also
new_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), name='inputs_new_name') 
# here you need to state the name of the placeholder you used in your original input placeholder  

saver = tf.import_graph_def(path/to/.meta, input_map={"original_inputs_placeholder_name:0": new_placeholder})
saver.restore(/path/to/your_checkpoint)
```

Comment: I get a shape mismatch error when doing this: Shapes are not compatible